# How to use selector :removed in cytoscape.js?

Tags: cytoscape.js

How can I get removed eles from the graph?
cy.filter(":removed") doesn't work and cy.elements() doesn't have removed eles.

Thanks!

Comment: please provide what you have tried so far.

Comment: `cy.add({group: "nodes", data: {id: "n1"}}); cy.$("#n1").remove(); var removed = cy.filter(":removed"); console.log(removed.length);`

Comment: `console.log(removed.length)` returns 0.   Maybe I don't understand something.

Answer (score 2):

Cytoscape.js does not keep removed elements in the graph.  That would contradict that they're removed.  So, of course if you ask the graph for all removed elements, it will return to you an empty collection -- i.e. there are no removed elements in the graph.

The `:removed` selector exists for completeness and so you can use it on your own collections.  If you have a collection for which you've held onto a reference, some elements may be removed later on but they'll still be in the referenced collection.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remember which nodes you removed and then call restore on them:

```
var removed = [];

function remove(elements)
{
 removed.push(elements);
 selected.remove();
}

function restore()
{
    cy.startBatch();
    for (var i = 0; i < removed.length; i++)
    {
        removed[i].restore();
  }
    removed = [];
    cy.endBatch();
}
```

For some reason, removing takes a long time on a large graph. And if you only remove and restore nodes, their connected edges are gone.